# Drawing a rectangle around a toolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#, graphics, toolstripitem

I know that I can draw rectangles just about anywhere I want using

```
using (Graphics G = myControl.CreateGraphics())
{
    G.DrawRectangle(new Pen(myColor),myControl.Bounds);
}
```

but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this with a toolStripMenuItem, so that I can draw a rectangle around it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the Paint event (you should rarely ever use CreateGraphics) and the ContentRectangle property:

```
void toolStripButton1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, toolStripButton1.ContentRectangle);
}
```

Comment: This is more what I was looking for. I created a generic paint method to which I can attach and detach at will the `Paint` event of my toolstripmenuitems. This way I control which menuitem gets the rectangle without having a separate paint method for each. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to inherit from the control and override the `OnPaint` method, then change all instances of `ToolStripMenuItem` to `MyToolStripMenuItem`.

```cs
class MyToolStripMenuItem : ToolStripMenuItem
{
    protected override void OnPaint( PaintEventargs pe )
    {
        base.OnPaint( pe );

        pe.ClipRectangle.Inflate( -1, -1 );
        pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle( Pens.Black, pe.ClipRectangle );
    }
}
```

A bit more complicated, but better in the long run for maintainability, is implementing a custom [ToolStripRenderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriprenderer(v=vs.110).aspx) which would allow you to change the look of the entire thing, for example making it look like VS2010.

[image]

*(Image taken from [VBForums](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?611712-Ready-Visual-Studio-2010-Menu-ToolStrip))*

Comment: I like this solution for greater customization of the toolstripmenuitem! However, I only want to paint the rectangle sometimes, so subclassing isn't necessary for me. Thanks for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

While `ToolStripMenuItem` is not a control, its parent is. Therefore you can call

```cs
myToolStripMenuItem.GetCurrentParent().CreateGraphics()
```